# Symfony2: Create routes dynamicaly (on the fly)

Tags: symfony, routes

I have a Symfony2 project and I would like to be able to create routes on the fly. For example, I have a database conected with the project and for each element from a specific table, I would like to create a route like `main/help/$help_id`.

I can't find a tutorial on how to do it.

Comment: i believe that your problem can be solved without routes on the fly ,with wildcardz. but you arent very specific. If you feel that you should add routes you should probably hook this component http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/routing.html

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/dic_tags.html#routing-loader  this might help also

Comment: Thank you very much @Parhs, I will try this and if it works, I will let you know. You could then post the answer so I can accept.

Comment: http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/symfony2-dynamically-add-routes/   this is an example how to use this tag

Comment: I sow tha last one but I have problems with making this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely do **not** need dynamic routes for that.

```
my_route:
    pattern: /main/help/{help_id}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Help:show }
```

Then, in your controller action:

```
class HelpController
{
    public function show($help_id)
    {
        // Find your help item in the database.

        if ($help_item) {
            // Display your help item.
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The help item you requested was not found');
        }
    }
}
```